# 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version

Tags: sql, mariadb

```
sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO record1 (s_id,s_date,s_in_time,s_p) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)"
       SELECT s_id, s_date, s_in_time, s_out_time, s_p 
       FROM staff_attendance 
       WHERE staff_attendance.s_id 
         AND staff_attendance.s_date != record.s_id 
         AND record.s_date
```

I am using this query to populate my data, I want only that entries enter into the database which are unique

Comment: What language is this? C? Java? Can you show the complete code? How are you substituting the `%s`?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help, as would an explanation of the logic you want to implement.  Your query makes no sense.

Comment: In the present form these lines cannot be syntactically correct. In the first line you put an SQL statement into a variable, but no substitution for the %s placeholders appear. After that a SELECT statement appears, but no precompiler directive, and no variable or other construction are there to deal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the `values` statement is not necessary.

Second, you have a reference to the table `record`, which doesn't exist.

I suspect that you want no duplicates on `s_id/s_date` (although that is a guess).  You need to start with a unique index/constraint on whatever you want.  So, start with that (if it doesn't exist):

```
create index unq_record1_s_id_s_date on record1(s_id, s_date);
```

Then, I would recommend `on duplicate key update` rather than `insert ignore`.  This allows the statement to capture other types of errors:

```
insert into record1 (s_id, s_date, s_in_time, s_out_time, s_p)
    select sa.s_id, sa.s_date, sa.s_in_time, sa.s_out_time, sa.s_p 
    from staff_attendance sa
    on duplicate key update s_id = values(s_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a insert select   you should use

```
  INSERT IGNORE INTO record1 (s_id,s_date,s_in_time,s_p) 
  SELECT s_id, s_date, s_in_time,  s_p 
  FROM staff_attendance 
  WHERE staff_attendance.s_id 
     AND staff_attendance.s_date != record.s_id 
      AND record.s_date
```